# apache suexec "command not in docroot"

Tags: linux, perl, apache, suexec

Error message is:

```
command not in docroot (/home/site1/cgi-bin/test.pl).
```

[Here](https://wincent.com/wiki/Troubleshooting_suexec_errors) I found this:

> suexec requires the CGI script to be under the server's DocumentRoot (not the VirtualHost DocumentRoot). It is permitted, however, for the VirtualHost DocumentRoot to be a symlink to a directory that appears under the real DocumentRoot.

a part of virtual host config is:

```
[...]
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /home/site1/htdocs

SuexecUserGroup site1 site1

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/site1/cgi-bin/
<Location /home/site1/cgi-bin>
           Options +ExecCGI
</Location>

<Directory /home/site1/>
Options -Includes -Indexes -FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI MultiViews
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
AllowOverride none
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
[...]
```

So, I prefer have Perl scripts inside cgi-bin, but if I can't resolve this problem I can move all scripts to htdocs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`suEXEC` has its own `docroot` which is totally independent of whatever you configure in your Apache config. You can see what `suEXEC`'s docroot is by calling:

```
suexec -V
```

You may need to be root for that. In my case the docroot was `/var/www`. You'll have to put your scripts there. There is no way to change this save recompiling `suEXEC`. Don't try to use symbolic links to keep your scripts outside of `/var/www` (or whatever your `suEXEC` is configured to).

Edit: as mentioned by @insaner in the comments the command is probably `suexec` or as I have seen on at least one server `suexec2`. `suEXEC` is just what the Apache documentation calls the module/feature.

Comment: The package `apache2-suexec-custom` allows for more flexibility.

Comment: Excelent. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Fantastic! I was using a symlink which unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Check that docroot directory exist. for example if your docroot is "/home" , /home directory must exist. and you can run commands in /home1 /home2 and ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a config in `/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data` with below first 2 lines if you are using `apache2-suexec-custom` package.

```
/var/www
public_html/cgi-bin
```

You need to replace those lines with your setup. There SHOULD be 2 lines. Giving only one line will through error.

I used something like below,

```
home
cgi-bin
```

Answer (score -4):

Change DocumentRoot `/home/site1/htdocs` to DocumentRoot `/home/site1/`